# Custom operations using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, batch-processing, java-stream

I am implementing a batch program in java. The flow is as follows: I fetch data from a database convert the data into custom objects and then put those objects in a queue. Then the goal is to run some profiling logic (for example nlp) afterwards. A friend of mine told me I should consider using the java stream api since it supports parallel processing. I am relatively new to Java 8 so my question is where to put(or execute) the mentioned profiling logic? Is there a way to create custom operations or do I have to implement a custom Collector?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends what you are doing with those objects. This doesn't seem like a job for Java 8 streams at all - it seems like a job for a much more high level framework, such as [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/); where you can configure complex pipelines of commands to be carried out on "messages", which would be your objects.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The question is very vague so it's hard to make recommendations. Suggesting spring based on so little information is maybe a bit extreme...

Comment: You would model your logic as a `map` operation which transforms each object into the result of your NLP processing. Then you can use a standard Collector to put all results into a list, or maybe aggregate them in some way. Much is provided out of the box. For parallelization of IO-based streams I would advise looking [here](https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams).

Comment: **map** was what I was looking for. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @MarkoTopolnik **map** is the solution.